# Cognito User Pool Authentication in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have developed an iOS and Android application which gather data from cars which is sent to an AWS DynamoDB. The user sign in through the mobile app using the Cognito User Pool.

Now I want to develop a web page to present the user's data. For this purpose, the user has to provide his credential to the web page (SSL) which are used to retrieve his information from the database. The code below works well (the html form to get user/password in not shown):

```
<script src="jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="jsbn2.js"></script>
<script src="sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/aws-sdk-2.3.5.js"></script>
<script src="aws-sdk.js"></script>
<script src="aws-sdk.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function completeAndRedirect() {

        var authenticationData = {
            Username : document.getElementById("UserID").value,
            Password : document.getElementById("Password").value,
        };

        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
        var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-west-.......',
            ClientId : '...................'
        };
        var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
        var userData = {
            Username : 'test',
            Pool : userPool
        };
        var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

        console.log('userid:'+authenticationData.Username);
        console.log('pass:'+authenticationData.Password);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            },

            onFailure: function(err) {
                console.log('test');
                alert(err);
            },

        });
    }
</script>
```

However, the javascript will run on the client side and include all the needed API and secret keys.

I read that php is preferred as everything will stay on the server side.
However, I have not found any examples or references pointing me to the right direction.

I am puzzled for now as I do not know how to move forward as it does not seem that Amazon recommend to use php given all the examples in JavaScript and related comment on their forum:[User Pool Authentication using Php](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231616&tstart=0#720739)

Any recommendation to address this problem in addition to JavaScript encryption to obfuscate the keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cognito User pools with Cognito Federated identity service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html).

The Cognito Federated Identity service vends your clients temporary AWS credentials which can be used to authenticate with any other AWS service, which your control through Federated Identity Pool roles. You will not be required to embed your AWS access and secret keys in the JavaScript app and you will be able to interact with AWS services securely.

Code example can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples-user-pool-identity-pool).

Comment: So in summary the bare minimum to achieve the user authentication and get access to AWS service are:

Comment: So in summary the bare minimum to embed in javascript to achieve the user authentication and get access to AWS services are: Identity pool id, User pool id and Client id. Is it correct? If so is it safe to leave them in clear?

Comment: Yes. Client Id is an easy to revoke resource. If at some point you think it has been compromised, you can revoke that particular client and start using a new client for your app. User pool id and identity pool id alone are not enough to perform any meaningful action.